# Get CDF of one variable conditional Probability

Tags: probability-theory

Let $U\sim\text{Unif}[0,Z]$ and $Z\sim\text{Unif}[1,e^2]$.
I'm interested in the CDF of $U$.

From the above, we can write the densities:
$$f_{U\mid Z}(u\mid z)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{z} &0\leq u\leq z\\0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

From here, I tried to integrate to get the pdf of $U$, but am not confident in my work.
$$f_U(u) = \int_1^{e^2} f_{U\mid Z}(u\mid z) f_Z(z)\mathrm{d}z$$
I got $\frac{2}{e^2-1}$ from this integral.  Is this correct?

I also have the following notational question.
I've seen that $F(t) = P(U =< t) = \int P(U\leq t\mid Z = z)f(z)\mathrm dz$. I thought the notation $P(U\leq t\mid Z = z)$ was already the CDF, and am confused about this notation.  I'd appreciate if someone could clarify this for me.

Comment: Clearly, $U$ takes on values between $0$ and $e^2$. If you integrate your "result" over this interval, do you get $1$? Densities have to integrate to 1.

Comment: My result in the denominator was e^2-1 l. Now if i integrate my result $$int 2/(e^2-1) du= 2u/(e^2-1) now is this the CDF of U. Because i am not sure how to deal with the intervals to get a complete CDF of U. I think that i missed the other interval 0=<u=<z

Answer (score 0):

Remember that 
$$f_{U|Z}(u|z)=\frac {f_{U,Z}(u,z)}{f_Z(z)}$$
Which implies that $$f_{U,Z}(u,z)=f_{U|Z}(u|z)f_Z(z)=\frac 1z \frac {1}{e^2-1}$$
Coupled with $$\int f_{U,Z}(u,z) \mathrm{d}z=\int\frac 1z \frac {1}{e^2-1}\mathrm{d}z=f_U(u)$$
You have to split the integral in two as follows: 

We know that $0\le u\le z$ and $1\le z\le e^2 \Rightarrow \max (u,1)\le z \le e^2$
From this we get two different bounds: 
$$0 \le u\le 1 \quad \mathrm{and} \quad 1\le z\le e^2 $$
$$1 \le u\le z \quad \mathrm{and} \quad u\le z\le e^2 $$
And our integral becomes: 
$$\int_1^{e^2}\frac 1z \frac {1}{e^2-1}\mathrm{d}z=\frac {2}{e^2-1} \quad 0\le u\le 1$$
And 
$$\int_u^{e^2}\frac 1z \frac {1}{e^2-1}\mathrm{d}z=\frac {2-\ln u}{e^2-1} \quad 1\le u\le e^2$$
Which means that our PDF is defined as:
$$ f_U(u) = \frac {1}{{e^2-1}}
\cases{ 2 & if $\quad 0\le u\le 1$\cr
        2-\ln u & if $\quad 1\le u\le e^2$\cr}$$

So you were just off by the bounds of $u$. 

With regards to your other question, $F_X(t)=\mathbb{P}(X<t)\ne \mathbb{P}(X<t|Z=z)$ the latter is conditional on $z$, and it is analogous to conditioning with discrete probabilities, where instead of integrating, you sum over all the partitions of the sample space, i.e.
$$\mathbb{P}(X=x)=\sum_i \mathbb{P}(X=x|Y=i)\mathbb{P}(Y=i)$$

Comment: Are the intervals that i used correct to obtain the CDF of U? Because i saw that for the interval of 1=<u=<e^2 the CDF turned out to be 3u-3In3-1/(e^2-1). And there they set up the pdf of U as u/z with 0 if u<0 , u/z if 0=<u=<z and 1 if u>=z. But i dont get that approach.

Comment: @Mark I added more information, including a correction to a mistake, since the PDF given before was incomplete. You will note that the expression you gave for $f_U$ integrated to $\frac {2e^2}{e^2-1}\ne 1$ hence it was incorrect.

Comment: Thank you!  So if i integrate 2-Inu/e^2-1 the result will be 3u-3In3-1/(e^2)? Or 3u-3In3/(e^2-1) without the -1?

Comment: @Mark you will get $\frac {3u-u\ln u}{e^2-1}$

Answer (score 0):

Let's calculate the integral to check your work for the first part.

The densities $f_{U\mid Z}$ and $f_Z$ are correct.  So, we can write:
$$f_U(u) = \int_1^{e^2} f_{U\mid Z}(u\mid z)f_Z(z)\mathrm{d}z$$
just as you did.  Substituing in our densities, we get that:
$$f_U(u) = \int_1^{e^2}\frac{1}{z}\chi_{[0,z]}(u)\frac{1}{e^2-1}\mathrm{d}z$$
Here, I'm using a characteristic function $\chi_{[0,z]}(u)$. These are defined as:
$$\chi_{[0,z]}(u) = \begin{cases} 1 & u\in[0,z] \\ 0 & u\not\in[0,z]\end{cases}$$
Now, as $U\sim\text{Unif}(0,Z)$, we have that $u\in[0,z]$. So, the characteristic function is always $1$, and we get that:
$$f_U(u) = \int_1^{e^2} \frac{1}{e^2-1}\frac{1}{z}\mathrm{d}z = \frac{1}{e^2-1}\ln(e^2) = \frac{2}{e^2-1}$$
So, it seems like this is the right answer.

Regarding the integral of the CDF, it does show up, but not in the way you're stating it.  Suprisingly, the following identity holds:
$$E[X] = \int_0^\infty (1-F_X(t))\mathrm{d}t$$
Her,e $1-F_X(t)$ is known as the *complementary* cdf.
To see this, we can integrate by parts:
\begin{align*}
u & = 1-F_X(t),\quad \mathrm{d}v = \mathrm{d}t \\
\mathrm{d}u & = -f_X(t)\mathrm{d}t,\quad v = t \\
\int_0^\infty 1- F_X(t)\mathrm{d}t & =\left(t(1-F_X(t))\right|_0^\infty+\int_0^\infty tf_X(t)\mathrm{d}t
\end{align*}
On the left part, putting in $0$ clearly gives us $0$.
The infinite limit gives an indeterminate form, which seems to require a little work to justify, but as this isn't the main point of this post just assume it goes to $0$.
Then, we get that:
$$\int_0^\infty (1-F_X(t))\mathrm{d}t = E[X]$$

I haven't seen $\int_0^\infty F_X(t)\mathrm{d}t$, but there may be some usage for it.  You'd have to clarify your question to address it sufficiently.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification regarding the last part of my question.

Comment: Are the intervals that i used correct to obtain the CDF of U? Because i saw that for the interval of 1=<u=<e^2 the CDF turned out to be 3u-3In3-1/(e^2-1). And there they set up the pdf of U as u/z with 0 if u<0 , u/z if 0=<u=<z and 1 if u>=z. But i dont get that approach.